# BSD socket header

Tags: linux, sockets, bsd

The socket.h BSP header that has the '__P' as

> int   bind __P((int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t))

Could you tell me what is the meaning of '__P' here? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a portability hack.  K&R C (the version before C was standardized by ANSI and ISO) didn't declare functions with types and named arguments in the parentheses.  As a consequence, this declaration needs to be this on K&R C:

```
int bind();
```

and this on standard C:

```
int bind(int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);
```

The `__P` macro is designed to paper over these differences and allow the compiler to generate the appropriate prototype depending on the existence of the `__STDC__` macro which specifies standard C.

Note that C was standardized by ANSI in 1989 and by ISO in 1990, and has gone through several revisions since then, most notably in 1999 and 2011.  It is highly unlikely that anyone is still using a K&R C compiler on a modern system because for many architectures, their support in the operating system in question appeared only in compilers which supported standard C.  Also, most people are using systems which have been upgraded or built in the past 30 years.

However, some very old software may be written in K&R C, and as such, this technique allows such code to work.  The lifetime of such code is necessarily limited, though, as the latest versions of GCC and clang don't support K&R C anymore, so finding an old compiler may be tricky.

Comment: Appreciate your answer!